# Wordpress Multisite thousands of tables

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have a WordPress multisite that users create their own blogs and post articles. The problem that I have is that each new blog create about 10 tables and InnoDB has a limit of 4b tables. Is there any way to force multisite to don' t create those tables?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot stop a multi-site install creating new tables because the have to be there for the site to work. When a new site is created, it needs to create a new set of unique tables to store the new sites data in and does this with unique prefixes (such as `wp_4_options` for site 4 etc).

There is a method called [`sharding`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)) where you can split tables into multiple databases. I believe Automattic use the [HyperDB plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/) to achieve this on WordPress.com.

That's probably the best way to ensure that tables are evenly spread out so you don't hit a limit. Whilst it could potentially be possible to have one set of tables for each site, you'd need to modify the database structure and that is bad and can get messy.